# DRF authentication classes decorator not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have faced a problem that authentication_classes decorator is not working. Guess, there must be some error in my code

views.py

```
@authentication_classes([authentication.BaseAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(['GET'])
def profile(request):
    # some logic
    
    return Response()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r"profile/", profile, name='profile'),
]
```

When I send request without any auth data on this endpoint I don't get 401 error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in decorators order. First should be `api_view`

Answer (score 0):

**this will help in understanding of execution**

```
# 1st decorator function
def decorator_one(function):
    def wrapper1():
        print("decorator_one will call : ", function.__name__)
        return function()
    return wrapper1


# 2nd decorator function
def decorator_two(function):
    def wrapper2():
        print("decorator_two will call : ", function.__name__)
        return function()
    return wrapper2


@decorator_two
@decorator_one
def hello():
    print("hello function")
    return 'Hello XYZ'


print(hello())


## output
decorator_two will call :  wrapper1
decorator_one will call :  hello
hello function
Hello XYZ
```